# Can it ever be appropriate to mix async with manually starting tasks in an MVC/WebApi application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm building a `WebApi` application that will be hosted in an Azure website, and I'm using `async` calls where appropriate. However, the powers that be want me to make the logging happen in a separate thread from the calling method so as to continue processing the the actual business logic while some "worker task" handles the logging.

A sample scenario would look like this:

Request comes into `async` action -> calls `await businessComponent.ProcessAsync(args)` -> calls synchronized `_logger.Log(message, args)` -> creates `new Task(() => FormatAndWrite(message, args)` , set `task.ConfigureAwait(false)`, calls `task.Start()`

So I want somebody more experienced with `async/await` and the way `ASP.NET` handles `async/await` to tell me if they see a major problem with the solution above? Would this be something that can potentially save time when processing the actual business logic request?

Comment: This is only an acceptable approach if it's OK for you to miss logs occasionally.

Comment: Is this because the execute of FormatAndWrite may not execute before the incoming request finishes and returns?

Comment: Indirectly, yes. ASP.NET will occasionally recycle your application, but it will not recycle if there are requests being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can shorten that specific request by using multiple threads to process it (that's assuming your business logic has at least some CPU bound work to do).

However by using multiple threads per request you can handle less requests concurrently with the same amount of available threads. So it's a tradeoff.

If the goal is to offload that work to the `ThreadPool` use `Task.Run` explicitly instead of `new Task(...).Start` and make sure you `await` it before leaving the `async` handling the request. Background tasks in ASP.Net can be stopped without you knowing.

Comment: See the thing is I've tried to research this a bit and have come across a number of articles stating 3 problems which lead me to asking my question: 1. Only use await if there's a clear advantage because await is expensive under the hood (this is too much for our logging.) 2. Don't mix await/async with Task.Run in ASP.NET because of 3. Task.Run apparently asks the ThreadPool for a new thread that it was not expecting to create since it isn't a new request coming in. So I'm not sure what's right...

Comment: @IWriteApps 1. I doubt `await` is more expensive than this blocking IO operation. 3. The `ThreadPool` doesn't usually create threads. It's a pool of already created ones. It will create new threads only if it runs out of them.

Comment: @IWriteApps The real issue as I understand it with `Task.Run` is as Stephen Cleary mentioned, your app can be recycled if it isn't currently handling requests. By `await`ing the task returned from Task.Run you're keeping that request alive. You can also not wait for it but realize you may lose logs.